# how to instantiate an array whose length uses template parameter in a template function

Tags: c++, templates

I want to instantiate an array length like this way:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<size_t M, size_t N>
void instanBoolArr(size_t M, size_t N)
{
    bool a[M];
    bool b[N];

}

int main(void)
{
    size_t M = 1;
    size_t N = 1;
    instanBoolArr(M, N);
    return 0;
}
```

But the clang compiler told me the error messages :

> prog.cc:6:27: error: declaration of 'M' shadows template parameter
>   void instanBoolArr(size_t **M**, size_t N)
>
> prog.cc:5:17: note: template parameter is declared here
>   template
>
> prog.cc:6:37: error: declaration of 'N' shadows template parameter
>   void instanBoolArr(size_t M, size_t **N**)
>
> prog.cc:5:27: note: template parameter is declared here
>   template
>
> prog.cc:9:10: warning: unused variable 'b' [-Wunused-variable]
>       bool b[N];
>
> prog.cc:8:10: warning: unused variable 'a' [-Wunused-variable]
>       bool a[M];
>
> prog.cc:17:5: error: no matching function for call to 'instanBoolArr'
>       instanBoolArr(M, N);
>
> prog.cc:6:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template
>   argument 'M' void instanBoolArr(size_t M, size_t N)

The version of clang compiler is 7.0.

I want to implement it in this way, but I su*k at C++ template and I didn't find the useful answer for me in the net.

So, if not mind, PLZ someone points my faults and helps me through it.

Sincerely.

Comment: errors spell it out. No need to pass `size_t M, size_t N` as arguments  to the function. They shadow the template parameters. Without them you can call your function like `instanBoolArr<1, 2>()`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler errors are pretty clear. Your function parameters are shadowing your template parameters.

Change your function to:

```
template<size_t M, size_t N>
void instanBoolArr()
{
    bool a[M];
    bool b[N];
}
```

Comment: You might want to show how they would call it, just to make it more complete.

Comment: I get it. But if I have to pass M, N as the function parameter which is same with the template parameter, which is the question I have to face it now, I do not how to get it right, if I want to pass the function parameter as same as the template parameter.

Comment: @FreAkPoint: I have no idea what you mean and what you're trying to do. Can you elaborate?